# Is remote services used by other applications in Android?

Tags: android, service

If I create a remote service in my app then will it accessible to other apps too. I want that it should not be accessible to other apps. But I need to create a remote service since it needs to keep running in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I create a remote service in my app then will it accessible to other apps too.

Yes. That is the point behind having a remote service.

> I want that it should not be accessible to other apps.

Then do not make a remote service.

> But I need to create a remote service since it needs to keep running in the background.

A remote service will not "keep running in the background", any more than a local service will "keep running in the background". You cannot write a service that will "keep running in the background" very long. That is because developers have tried writing services that "keep running in the background", causing problems for users. Users have responded with task killers, and the Android OS has responded by terminating services that run too long.

If your service is part of the foreground user experience (e.g., a music player), use `startForeground()` and a `Notification` to minimize the odds of your service being terminated.

Otherwise, please redesign your application to not require a service that will "keep running in the background". For example, to do some work every 15 minutes, use `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService`.

Comment: Actually, I want to call a web service every 5 minutes. I will try and implement it the way you have suggested i.e. IntentService and AlarmManager. If you can point me to some tutorial or example then it will be great. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by startForeground() method. I thought Android do not have any way of knowing whether the app is running in background or foreground.

Comment: I will also like to know what will happen if the app goes into background. Will AlarmManager still be invoked every 5 minutes to invoke the service.

Comment: I don't want to start the AlarmManager in OnBootCompleted receiver rather I will like to call it in onCreate() method of Application class since that's the method when application is launched. Also, suppose if the application is force stoped from settings then will the alarmmanager too stopped.

Comment: I have followed your WakefulIntentService example but its giving me InstantiationException for the AppService class.

Comment: "Also, what do you mean by startForeground() method." -- if you look in the upper-right corner of http://developer.android.com, you will find a search box. Please learn how to use it. "Will AlarmManager still be invoked every 5 minutes to invoke the service." -- yes, until you cancel the alarm. "I don't want to start the AlarmManager in OnBootCompleted receiver rather I will like to call it in onCreate() method of Application class since that's the method when application is launched." -- that makes little sense to me.

Comment: "Also, suppose if the application is force stoped from settings then will the alarmmanager too stopped." -- yes. The user is saying that they do not want your application to run. Please respect the user's wishes.

Comment: "I have followed your WakefulIntentService example but its giving me InstantiationException for the AppService class." -- use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine the stack trace associated with your exception. Further down the stack trace it should indicate to you what the real problem is. Also, make sure your service class and constructor are both `public`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to run the sample and will implement that way in the application.